# gwtent reflection java

Tags: java, gwt, reflection

Welcome,
I have a problem with "GWTENT" reflection.

How to create a class using reflection?

I tried this:

```
 try {
            ClassType ct = TypeOracle.Instance.getClassType(Klient.class);
            ct.invoke(null, "Klient", null);
        } catch (ReflectionRequiredException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 `
```

call the class:

```
package pl.cba.lukaszbaczek.client.Test;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.gwtent.reflection.client.Reflectable;
import com.gwtent.reflection.client.Reflection;

@Reflectable
public class Klient extends Window implements Reflection {

    @Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);
        setHeading("Klient");
        setSize(600, 600);
    }

    public Klient(){
        super();
        show();

    }
}
```

But fails with the error:

```
17:30:59.129 [ERROR] [makerbase] Uncaught exception escaped
com.gwtent.reflection.client.NotFoundException: Klient not found or unimplement?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the client side which is compiled into javascript you cannot use reflection. You can use GWT.create(Clazz.class) but the class signature must be known at compile time. This is a requirement due to the javascript compiler.

Here is a link that uses generators for doing reflection
[Can you use Java Reflection api in GWT client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195233/can-you-use-java-reflection-api-in-gwt-client)