# Log with Class Name and Function Name

Tags: gwt

I need to to a GWT log that will prefix the Class Name + Function Name, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that requires reflection, which isn't supported in GWT as far as I know.

See this question for more details:
[Can you use Java Reflection api in GWT client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195233/can-you-use-java-reflection-api-in-gwt-client)