# Comparing POJOs on the client side in a GWT application

Tags: gwt, comparison, client-side, pojo

I have some objects that are displayed in a GWT table, the user can make changes to these in the browser and when they click save I want to be able to generate a summary of the changes i.e. what fields have changed for what object.

I thought of using the apache commons `CompareToBuilder` for comparison and using a library that uses `reflection` to find what fields have changed, but the problem is that I can't use commons on the client side of a GWT app neither can I use reflection.

Is there a nice way to do this on the client side without having to manually compare each property in the `compareTo` method. I would preferably like to do this in a generic way so that it works with any POJO. I don't want to do this on the server side because semantically it makes sense to do this on the client side, if however there is no way possible then I'm willing to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.You can do it on client side it self.

GWT Reflection is a small framework which give you ability to use reflection API on client side (yes! on browse side!) of application.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-reflection/

Hope that helps(*Ignore if you do not want any third party plugins*).

And a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195233/can-you-use-java-reflection-api-in-gwt-client) here.

Comment: I'm looking at this and was wondering if there was something more polished?